# Unable to login to salesforce - Lightning to Outlook Sync

Tags: loginflow, salesforce-outlook-sync

Users are unable to login to Salesforce from outlook  if these users have a login flow for their profile. 
Has anyone experience this ? If so, what did you do?

Seems like an issue with Salesforce login flow/ outlook integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has acknowledged this as a bug, and are currently working on it. the expected release is Summer 19 (safe harbor)

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. @user4947 - What are you basing that on? This is all I could find on the Salesforce 'Known Issues' site: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003UnkQAE I also wasn't able to find anything related to this in the [Summer '19 release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/salesforce_release_notes.htm).

Comment: @MoH I am basing that on the response i received from Salesforce for my ticket, and the telephone conversation I had with Salesforce Support.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that seems like an issue (aka a bug), you should be able to parse the user agent in the login flow or the platform to determine if they are coming from outlook and bypass the login flow in that case.

[See this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow_examples.htm&type=5) for the variables that you have access to in your login flow.  Will take some experimentation / analytics to determine the best values to filter on, but should be possible to bypass the flow for outlook client and will take less time than logging a support case (and you may get shut down bc you need premiere support for visual workflow issues).

Copying the variables below for reference.

> LoginFlow_LoginType
>
> LoginFlow_IpAddress
>
> LoginFlow_UserAgent
>
> LoginFlow_Platform
>
> LoginFlow_Application
>
> LoginFlow_Community
>
> LoginFlow_SessionLevel
>
> LoginFlow_UserId

Comment: Thanks @gorav  for your suggestion. I will try to bypass the outlook logins from the flow. You are right, about being shut down for not being a premier support account.