# How to prevent a login flow from applying under certain circumstances?

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, loginflow

My login flow prevents users from logging in to Salesforce for Outlook. This seems to be [due to a bug](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003UnkQAE):

[image]

Gorav has suggested [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249674/unable-to-login-to-salesforce-lightning-to-outlook-sync/262095) that it "should be possible to bypass the flow for outlook client".

However, I'm not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook will send a HTTP request with a User-Agent HTTP header that will identify it as a client. Modify the login flow to look for that header and make decisions in the flow based on that. Unfortunately there's no definitive reference for values of User-Agent sent by different Outlook releases running on multiple platforms. For example, Outlook 2016 on Windows 10 sends this as User-Agent:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Microsoft Outlook 16.0.9126; Microsoft Outlook 16.0.9126; ms-office; MSOffice 16)
```

As you can see, looking for substring "Microsoft Outlook 16.x.yyyy" in this particular User-Agent header will get you what you want. You can experiment with all other Outlook versions and platform variations and get the complete picture of User-Agent in your logs, then use that to create a comprehensive rule in your login flow.

Comment: Excellent thank you, but what action can I take upon detecting an Outlook login to prevent this issue from occurring?

As you can see in the screenshot above, the issue occurs after the flow terminates.

Comment: At the start of the flow, add this check. If the check criteria are met, exit the flow. That would terminate it.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't resolve the issue. I tried setting the flow to go to a decision element with no outcomes (for testing purposes) - the same issue occurred. I also tried setting the flow to go to a decision element, and then directly to a screen with a 'finish' button. Clicking the 'finish' button doesn't end the login process - it just tries to load something indefinitely. Any other ideas? Is there another way to exit the flow?

Comment: Exit the flow by redirecting them wherever you want them to go (versus this login page). https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_concepts_finish.htm&type=5

Comment: So I tried following the instructions in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_concepts_finish_override.htm&type=5) to set up a Lightning component that uses the navigateToSObject Lightning event to redirect flow users to a particular record. I then created a 'core action'  within the login flow to launch the Lightning component. However, this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: A) In Salesforce for Outlook, the same issue occurs, B) when logging in to the org via a web browser, the redirection does not occur, C) when launching the flow via an object-specific action on a record, the redirection occurs - so I know that the flow and Lightning component were set up properly. They just don't seem to work in the context of a login flow. I posted a question about redirecting flow users to a URL (which could help resolve this issue) on [this page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263728/how-to-redirect-flow-users-to-a-url). Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I managed to redirect the login flow, however, now I receive [this error](https://i.imgur.com/LvTnyoN.png) - the flow tries to redirect to the Lightning home page (/lightning/page/home). Any ideas?

Comment: @MoH Please post a new question

Comment: The original question hasn't been answered, redirecting the flow doesn't prevent it from applying. Furthermore, the same issue is still occurring - ie. users are not able to log in to Salesforce for Outlook because of the login flow. Therefore, I don't see any reason to post a new question. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @MoH Good luck with that strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, where the excel connector would be stuck after logging in after the flow finished. I unchecked the "Render Flow in Lightning Runtime" box and it resolved the issue. I'm not sure if the same would apply to Outlook, but wanted to post in case it helps anyone else.