# How to Redirect Flow Users to a URL?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, lightning-web-components

As you may be aware, it's possible to [Redirect Flow Users with a Local Action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_concepts_finish_override.htm&type=5). The example in the hyperlinked article demonstrates how to redirect flow users to a record using the **navigateToSObject** Lightning event.

I'd like to open a URL instead. How can I achieve this? Note that I still need to pass on the **record ID** from the flow to the Lightning Component as it is needed in the URL.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried navigateToURL or lightning: navigate?  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/specification

Comment: NavigateToURL worked, thank you! Would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NavigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/specification) should work - i believe you can use any of the lightning navigation methods.